# mrepo configuration iso setup?

Tags: linux

I'm about to setup a mrepo and I have a quick question. I would like to mount the Latest ISO and need to update the OS from that. I'm bit confused with ISO configuration. Do I need to mount ISO as loop device and copy the files into srcdir ? Or Mrepo would mount as loop device?

Answer (score 1):

mrepo will mount it itself, you just have to specify it in the .conf file, like:

```
[rhel6-server]
name = Red Hat Enterprise Server $release ($arch)
release = 6
#arch = i386 x86_64 ia64 ppc s390 s390x
arch = x86_64
metadata = repomd repoview yum

### ISO images
iso = rhel-server-$release.?-$arch-dvd.iso
```

Along with other options in /etc/mrepo.conf.

Comment: IIRC you need fuse-iso for this to work.

Comment: It will use fuse-iso if it is installed, but it will also just use mount -o loop,ro (per /usr/bin/mrepo, approx line 510).